# Pandas double unmelt with new column names based on column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame that I am trying transpose from long to wide.

**Here is the data frame:**

[image]

**Here is the desired output:**

[image]

**Below is reproducible code** to make the data frame and also my attempt called `test`; I am part way there, but I am not sure how to unmelt again and concatenate the column names.

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": [1, 1, 1, 1],
        "cat": ["Cat100", "Cat100", "Cat200", "Cat200"],
        "n": ["N1", "N2", "N1", "N2"],
        "y": [3, 4.2, 2.1, 2.4],
    }
)

test = mydf.set_index(["x", "cat", "n"])["y"].unstack().reset_index()
test.columns = test.columns.tolist()
display(test)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: `mydf.pivot(['x','cat'],'n','y').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()`

Comment: then try `test = mydf.pivot(['x','cat'],'n','y')`

Comment: both of these return the same `ValueError: Length of passed values is 4, index implies 2.`

Comment: let's try `pivot_table()` then `mydf.pivot_table('y',['x','cat'],'n')` if you further need cleanup then `mydf.pivot_table('y',['x','cat'],'n').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()`

Comment: That does not throw an error, but it does not return the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
mydf['cat'] = mydf.cat +'_'+ mydf.n
mydf.drop('n', axis=1, inplace=True)


res = mydf.set_index(['x', 'cat']).rename(columns={'y':''}).unstack().reset_index()
res.columns = res.columns.map(''.join)
```

**res**

```
    x   Cat100_N1   Cat100_N2   Cat200_N1   Cat200_N2
0   1   3.0         4.2         2.1         2.4
```

Comment: Thanks, that is really close; I am struggling with flattening out the multilevel though, so that the result is just like the desired output in the OP

Comment: Actually `res.columns = [''.join(col) for col in res.columns.values]` and `res.columns = res.columns.map(''.join)` both give the desired output in the OP; but `res.columns = res.columns.map('_'.join)` adds extra "_" bits

Comment: @a11: Updated thanks for pointing this out. Didn't check that.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) to flatten the MultiIndex then [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to return `x` to a column:

```
new_df = mydf.pivot(index='x', columns=['cat', 'n'], values='y')
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.map('_'.join)
new_df = new_df.reset_index()
```

`new_df`:

```
   x  Cat100_N1  Cat100_N2  Cat200_N1  Cat200_N2
0  1        3.0        4.2        2.1        2.4
```